# A Greatest Common Divisor Question

Tags: number-theory

What is $GCD(a_0a_1\bmod N,a_0a_2\bmod N)$ where $GCD(a_0,a_1)$, $GCD(a_0,a_2)$, $GCD(a_1,a_2)$, $GCD(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ could each be non-trivial?

($a\bmod N$ here is remainder of $a$ divided by $N$).

Comment: $GCD(a_0a_1\bmod N,a_0a_1\bmod N)=a_0a_1\bmod N$, I think the two integers in the $GCD$ should be different...

Comment: @ClémentGuérin corrected.